# Is there a way to set type for a specific typescript generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

e.g.

```
interface IWithManyGenericTypes<First, Second, Third, Fourth> {
  prop1?: First,
  prop2?: Second,
  prop3?: Third,
  prop4?: Fourth
}
```

and I want to set type, e.g., `number`, for a specific generic type, e.g.:

```
const someObject: IWithManyGenericTypes<Third = number> = {
  prop3: 123
}
```

is there a way to do something like?

Comment: Try: `<Third extends number>` instead of `<Third = number>`

Comment: Stutje, it doesn't work, I've tried and this is what vscode says: `Generic type 'IWithManyGenericTypes<First, Second, Third, Fourth>' requires 4 type argument(s).`

Comment: [Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-wind-39ll3), does this help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Maybe [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wood-cw7ng?file=/src/index.ts) will explain better than me.

Comment: [This better?](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sun-invfm?)

Comment: yes, thanks! it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Discussed this in the comments but just adding an answer for closure.

You need to address the other generics as well in the right order. If you don't need them you can set them to `undefined` or `unknown`.

```
const someObject2:IWithManyGenericTypes<undefined,undefined, number, undefined> = {
  prop3: 123
}
```

For better usage or readability you can create an other interface that extends `IWithManyGenericTypes`

```
interface IWithThirdGenericType<Third> 
extends IWithManyGenericTypes<undefined, undefined, Third, undefined>{}

const someObject:IWithThirdGenericType<number> = {
  prop3: 123
}
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sun-invfm)